# Story identification about trolls under a bridge and gold coins

Tags: story-identification, movie

My husband and I went to see *Snow White and the Huntsman* tonight, and it sparked a memory in both of us of a scene from a different fantasy movie/TV show, but neither of us can place it.

What we remember is that the main character needs to cross a bridge, in which trolls or goblins live underneath. They leave a pile of gold coins (and maybe rubies?) on a stone pedestal thing on the bridge, and the troll lets them cross. However when the main character get to the other side, he/she is ambushed. Takes place in a forest.

We would have seen this somewhere between 1–6 years ago, however after thinking about it for a while, I'm not sure if it was something we rented, or saw in the theater. So it might be older than 6 years. I hope this sounds familiar to someone.

Comment: Hi.  I added the "movie" tag just to help clarify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually sounds very-much like a plot from [one of the episodes](http://www.tvrage.com/Once_Upon_a_Time/episodes/1065094780/recap) of the TV show "[Once Upon a Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843230/)". It also involves Snow White, so that may have helped trigger the memory.

Comment: FYI that first link is broken for me.